# I'm trying to change the style of a button with typescript

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a timer; just a simple, HTML timer.  Now, I'm trying to get it so that the first button (button1) changes the background colour of the button to #0000FF if var `button1` (the variable that determines what the button says) is "Pause" and to #00FF00 if var `button1` is anything else. Here's my HTML (note: I am using angular so it might look a little weird):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="timer">
      00:00:00
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button1" id="buuton" onclick="timeout(40, 1)">
        {{button1}}
      </button>
      &nbsp;
      <button class="button2">
        {{button2}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Here's my typescript (again might look a little weird):

```js
timeLeft: number //Time left in milliseconds
currTime: number //Time on stopwatch in milliseconds
button1: string //Button 1
button2: string //Button 2
timeout (ms: number, func: number) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (func == 0) {
      null
    } else if (func == 1) {
      if (this.button1 == "Pause") {
        document.getElementById("buuton").style.backgroundColor = "#0000ff"
      } else {
        document.getElementById("buuton").style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00"
      }
    }
  }, ms);
}
```

And here's my CSS:

```css
.timer {
  height: 3.5em;
  line-height: 3em;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.33em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.buttons {
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0.1vh;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-left: 0.33em;
}
.screen {
  position: fixed;
  height: 93.5vh;
  width: 99vw;
  left: 0.5vw;
  top: 0.5vh;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you please help me?
Edit 1 (16 Jun 2020 10:49:39) - No, there were no error messages.

Comment: Since you're using angular try `(click)=""` instead of `onclick=""`

If that is not the issue check the browser's console for error messages, and if there are any add them to your question, if there are none, mention that in your question too. 

Also try tagging the question with angular, that might get you a better response

Comment: @CodeMonkey thx!!!! that worked! umm... how do u upvote comments/mark them as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @CodeMonkey mentioned, change your `onclick` event listener to be `(click)` instead. When event binding in Angular, *we hook an event listener to get notified whenever an event is fired*. [Angular docs](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ang5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=wrapping+event+listener+in+parentheses+Angular&source=bl&ots=fMQ8tDVi43&sig=ACfU3U1TvZp9jYm16_Yqn2rndvtmd3sxow&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLhcbn44bqAhUMIjQIHXJ6C4oQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=wrapping%20event%20listener%20in%20parentheses%20Angular&f=false)

Since your using Angular, updating the click event listener for your `<button>` to `(click)="timeout(40, 1)"` fixes the issue. Wrapping the event listener `click` inside parentheses indicates that the component property is tied up with the `click` event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="timer">
    00:00:00
  </div>

  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button1" id="buuton" (click)="timeout(40, 1)">
      {{button1}}
    </button>
    &nbsp;
    <button class="button2">
      {{button2}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```